# Firefox 68.0 update causes API calls to return 403 after CSP report-uri POST requests

Tags: session, firefox, post, cookies, content-security-policy

After the most recent Firefox update (68.0), I am having problems with persistent session data.

When a user logs in, as the page loads, there are various expected CSP violations that send a POST request containing the violation report to the path report-uri directive contains.

Subsequent API GET requests to retrieve user data returns a 403 Forbidden, which (by design) redirects the user back to the login page. Since the user is logged in already, same API requests are sent that result in another 403, which leads to an infinite loop until after an arbitrary number of loops API requests return 200 OK.

All requests (both POST and GET) before and after the update are the same.

It seems to me that the fact that there are CSP report POST requests before the API requests changes something related to the session, which is used by the back-end to determine if the user has the correct privileges.

Could Firefox have changed something about the way it handles CSP report-uri requests or their responses change with the update?

What would be a good way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has just been updated to version 68.0.1. The update seems to have fixed this problem. Release notes don't seem to be related to this in a way I can make sense, but regardless, the problem is solved.